# How can a Turing machine accept infinite number of inputs?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, computation-models

How it is possible for a turing machine to process an infinitely long input ?

Comment: "infinite number" $\neq$ "infinitely long"

Comment: Why do you think it it?

Comment: The title and the question do not match. Either please change the title or change the question.

Comment: For instance, a machine that accepts the lenguage of chains of "ones" that are uneven, there are infinite number of chains of " ones", and so, the machine can accept infinite inputs

Comment: @rotia This needs careful phrasing. What you've demonstrated is a Turing machine that accepts _infinitely many_ inputs. "accept infinite inputs" means "accept inputs where a single input might be infinite": Turing machines don't deal with infinite strings.

Comment: @rotia My point was purely one about language. You keep writing "accepts infinite inputs" where I think you mean "accepts infinitely many inputs". These two phrases mean two different things.  "Infinite inputs" is just the plural of "infinite input": in other words, it means "multiple inputs, each of which contain infinitely many characters"; "infinitely many inputs" means "the number of different inputs is infinite"

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are completely right, what i meant is a machine that accepted an infinite quantity of inputs of finite length. I don't know how i didn't get it until now!

Comment: @DavidRicherby In spanish, i will say "la máquina acepta infinitas entradas", in spanish the word "infinita" is used to mean an infinite quantity of something and also something that is infinite. I did a very literal translation of the word, thinking the word "infinite" will have the same meaning in english that it has in spanish, that was the problem.

Comment: @rotia Yeah, I figured it was a translation issue. I feel very fortunate that I can write here in my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for a Turing machine to process an infinite length input in finite time, if the language is such that we can determine if a string is accepted or not just by looking at a finite prefix. But the trouble is how are you going to initialize the input tape with an infinite input?

As for how Turing machine accepts infinite number of inputs, it is easy, it accepts them one at a time, for each input.